# How to flip vertically all the letter at even positions in input element?

Tags: html, css, input, flip

I need to flip vertically all the letter at even positions while keeping the letters at the odd positions intact in  element. Now I'm using this css style: **-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg)**. But it flips the whole text in input element.

What should I do else? Or maybe it's possible in another element, not an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to select the letters within an element (or within the value of an element). Theoretically, a `:nth-letter()` pseudo-element would do the trick, but this doesn't exist.

You can however use JavaScript to take the value of the input, explode the string by character, wrap `span` elements around each character, put these elements into some other container, and do the transformation on `span:nth-of-type(even)`.

### CSS

```
#container > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
#container > span:nth-of-type(even) {
    color: purple;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {
    'use strict';

    $('#container').empty();
    $(this).val().split('').forEach(function (v) {
        $('#container').append('<span>' + v + '</span>');
    });

});
```

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFuSS/) to demonstrate this.