# How set css style to GWT TextBox text?

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

I'm trying to implement my own TextBox.

My goal is to add the following fucntion:
when user types text, first letter should be styled in a special way. I want to do these actions:

1. Create css styling file
2. Get TextBox's text property as html.
3. Set text something like `<span class="first_letter_style">S</span>ome text`

I tried to perform `textBox.setText("some HTML")` and the result was predictable - textBox simply treated html as a text=)

Also i tried textBox.getElement.getInnerHTML(), in order to copy it and slightly change with `setInnerHTML()` but I saw in debug mode `JavaScriptObject` doesn't have `getInnerHTML()` method. Strange message  -  I expected Element not JavaScriptObject.

My question is - how set text to GWT TextBox and force it to treat it as HTML not as simple text. I mean html tags should make sense.

Other idea is creating `ContentPanel` with `InlineHTML` and simply use `span` tag, but this approach has a great disadvantage - I have no idea how make DIV+Label behave as TextBox - cursor showing, highlight selection, selection on double click and other things.

**UPDATE**: Actually I need to span not only first element but each third letter. I found something  interesting [in other stackoverflow answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817878/how-to-flip-vertically-all-the-letter-at-even-positions-in-input-element) but I don't understand it. Also i shouldn't use `JQuery` and I can't understand what does answerer mean by

> "create other container and wrap each letter with span"

I think it's not good idea to create other container - I should perform changes inside textBox not in other widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done in a simple way of just manipulating a TextBox.

One way you could get it to work is by creating a TextBox and hiding its output, while simultaneously copying the text from it, modifying it to add the things you want, and displaying it in a div element.

You will probably run into a few issues, since some functionality will be lost, like selecting a fragment of text and deleting it. You may be able to reproduce it by handling appropriate events.

I created a sample widget like this, feel free to try it:

```
public class HTMLBox extends FlowPanel{

    //this will be the text shown
    private HTML html = new HTML();

    //this will be our text box with the text hidden
    private TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

    private KeyUpHandler handler = new KeyUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            String textToShow = decorateHtml(textBox.getText()); 
            html.setHTML(textToShow);
        }
    };

    private ClickHandler ch = new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            //makes clicking on the "html" element set focus on textBox, so that user can type
            textBox.getElement().focus();       
        }
    };

    //add any tags to the text
    //like make every third letter bold
    public String decorateHtml(String html) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < html.length(); i++) {
            if (i%3 == 0) {
                sb.append("<span style='font-weight:bold;'>" + html.charAt(i) + "</span>");
            } else {
                sb.append(html.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach() {
        super.onAttach();
        //height of html set to height of textBox -4
        html.getElement().getStyle().setHeight(textBox.getElement().getOffsetHeight()-4, Unit.PX);
        html.getElement().getStyle().setLeft(2.0, Unit.PX);
        html.getElement().getStyle().setBottom(2.0, Unit.PX);
    }

    public HTMLBox() {

        addDomHandler(ch, ClickEvent.getType());
        getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.RELATIVE);
        html.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE);
        textBox.getElement().getStyle().setColor("transparent");
        textBox.addKeyUpHandler(handler);
        textBox.getElement();
        add(textBox);
        add(html);
    }

}
```

Using backspace, home and end works no problem. You may need to adjust the styles. Here's how it looks:

[image: textbox_showing_html]

Comment: Thanks, I got your idea. About problems with selection, cursor rendering and so on - I think it's possible to imitate cursor and selection by applying `css` blink effect to bitwise OR symbol. I mean "|". Selection is listening selection on TextBox, getting interval of selection and setting `background color=blue` for approriate HTML letters wrapped by span.

Comment: you need to add   `getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID);`.

Comment: Yes, I have just done it=) One more question - when i put long text that doesn't fit into my div, it goes down, splitting by many rows. But real TextBox just hide extra letters and show them when user moves cursor. How add one line restriction to DIV? Is there any css element?

Comment: there is `getElement().getStyle().setOverflow(Overflow.HIDDEN);` but it works a bit different to how a textbox works. Try it yourself. But then you can set the textbox to `textBox.setMaxLength(x);` that should help evade the issue with overflowing.